# The instance of entity type 'Data' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'__id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Data' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'__id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

My DbContext class:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MetadataConfiguration());
    }
 }
```

My Repository class:

```
public class MetadataRepository : GenericRepository<Metadata>, IMetadataRepository
{
    private const string _className = nameof(MetadataRepository);
    private new readonly MyDBContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MetadataRepository(MyDBContext context, ILogger logger) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Metadata> GetMetadataAsync(string id)
    {
        string methodName = $"{_className}.{nameof(GetMetadataAsync)}";
        _logger.LogInformation($"{methodName} started with id = {id}");
        var query = await _context.Metadata.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.ToString() == id);
        _logger.LogInformation($"{methodName} exited with query = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query)}");
        return query;
    }
}
```

My Interface:

```
public interface IMetadataRepository : IGenericRepository<Metadata>
{
   Task<Metadata> GetMetadataAsync(string id);
}
```

My Entity Configuration class:

```
public class MetadataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Metadata>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Metadata> builder)
   {
       builder
         .HasNoDiscriminator()
         .ToContainer(nameof(MyDBContext.Metadata))
         .HasPartitionKey(x => x.PartitionKey)
         .HasKey(x => x.Id);
          builder.HasMany(x => x.Data);
          builder.Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");
    }
}
```

My Metadata object class:

```
public class Metadata
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("partitionKey")]
     public string PartitionKey { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty ("data")]
     public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
 }

 public class Data
 {
    public string? Key { get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm trying to seed data to my cosmosDB for the first iteration:

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(MyDBContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (context.Metadata.Count() == 0)
        {
           Metadata metadata = new Metadata()
           {
               Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
               PartitionKey = "UserResponse",
               Data = new List<Data>
                 {
                    new Data
                    {
                       Key = "illness",
                       Value = "Illness"
                    },
                    new Data
                    {
                       Key = "familyemergency",
                       Value = "Family emergency"
                    },
                    new Data
                    {
                       Key = "other",
                       Value = "Other"
                    }
                 }
           };

       //context.Entry<Metadata>(metadata).State = EntityState.Detached;
        context.Metadata.AddRange(metadata);    // Error occurs here
        context.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to seed the data to my CosmosDB's Metadata container for the first run.
In the `DbInitializer.cs` class, I'm ensuring the DB is created, then I'm checking if DB has `Count == 0` or not, if it's 0 then I'm inserting the data. But I'm getting the above said error whenever I try to Add data to Metadata container.
`context.Metadata.AddRange(metadata);` <- Error occurs here

I've tried various solution from other posts like adding **AsNoTracking()** or making the state as **Detached state**. But it's all futile.
I'm not sure where is this other instance getting created from which is pointing to the same id!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Data`, not `Metadata`. I have not worked with CosmosDB but it seems since you have not defined the id property for `Data` some kind of shadow one is created (the `__id`). Try defining `Id` for `Data` and fill it in too:

```cs
Metadata metadata = new Metadata()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    PartitionKey = "UserResponse",
    Data = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Key = "illness",
            Value = "Illness"
        },
        // ...
    }
};
```

Or try (it seems more appropriate) change `HasMany` to `OwnsMany`:

```cs
builder.OwnsMany(x => x.Data);
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. When I commented the data seed, it worked fine. But what should I do if I don't wanna add Id to Data property. I want to modify the object as it might break someplace.

Comment: @ShashankShukla have you tried the second option suggested (the one with `OwnsMany`, or maybe just removing `builder.HasMany(x => x.Data);` can also work)?

Comment: yup, `removing` also worked as well as changing `HasMany` to `OwnsMany` worked just fine. Thanks.